# How to stop a simplehttpserver in python from httprequest handler?

Tags: python, python-2.7, http

I am new to python and wrote a simple httpserver in python. I am trying to shut down the server from the request to the server. How can I achieve this functionality of calling a function of the server from the handler?

```
class MyHandler(SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        if self.path == '/shutdown':
            pass # I want to call MainServer.shutdown from here


class MainServer()
    def __init__(self, port = 8123):
        self._server = HTTPServer(('0.0.0.0', port), MyHandler)
        self._thread = threading.Thread(target = self._server.serve_forever)
        self._thread.deamon = True 


    def start(self):
        self._thread.start()

    def shut_down(self):
        self._thread.close()
```

Answer (score 3):

In short, do not use `server.serve_forver(..)`. The request handler has a `self.server` attribute that you can use to communicate with the main server instance to set some sort of flag that tell the server when to stop.

```
import threading
from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler,HTTPServer

class MyHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        if self.path == '/shutdown':
            self.server.running = False


class MainServer:
    def __init__(self, port = 8123):
        self._server = HTTPServer(('0.0.0.0', port), MyHandler)
        self._thread = threading.Thread(target=self.run)
        self._thread.deamon = True 

    def run(self):
        self._server.running = True
        while self._server.running:
            self._server.handle_request()

    def start(self):
        self._thread.start()

    def shut_down(self):
        self._thread.close()

m = MainServer()
m.start()
```

Answer (score 2):

The server is normally accessible from the handler through the `server` attribute. A HTTPServer that was started with `server_forerver` can be shut down with its... `shutdown()` method. Unfortunately, even if it is not documented, you cannot call shutdown from the thread that runs the server loop because it causes a deadlock. So you could write this in your `do_GET` handler method:

```
def do_GET(self):
    # send something to requester...
    if self.path == '/shutdown':
        t = threading.Thread(target = self.server.shutdown)
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()
```

This will cleanly let the thread to terminate, and you should also use it as you server `shut_down` method, because Python threads cannot be closed abruptly:

```
def shut_down(self):
    self._server.shutdown()
```

Comment: Very elegant and simple solution. Minor comment: You can make the "killer thread" a daemon in its constructor like `t = threading.Thread(target = self.server.shutdown, daemon=True)`. Then the `t.daemon=True` line is not needed.